# Difference between Garmin eTrex Legend HCx and eTrex 30?

Tags: gps, garmin

I have used etrex Legend HCx a lot and been satisfied. Now I've seen etrex 30 just for a while and it seems to me that the Legend is much more user friendly, good old menus with a lot of functionality, the display is great, whereas the display of etrex 30 feels a bit junky and cheap - it's kind of blurred.... I don't really understand why, as 30 is newer model. So why 30 seems to suck?

But I've not tested the eTrex 30 in the field. **Can you please tell me what are the differences between these models?** Is eTrex 30 more precise? I found no precision specificatin for it. For HCx it [should be 15 meters](http://www.garmin.cz/produkty/outdoor/mapove-gps/etrex-hcx-serie/etrex-legend-hcx.html).

I tried to find eTrex legend HCx on Garmin.com but I was not successful.

Comment: eTrex 30: Unit dimensions, WxHxD: 2.1″ x 4.0″ x 1.3″ (5.4 x 10.3 x 3.3 cm) Vista HCx: Unit dimensions, WxHxD: 2.2″ x 4.2″ x 1.2″ (5.6 x 10.7 x 3.0 cm) More about [GARMIN NUVI 52lm](http://garminnuvi52lm.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a comparison table between the two on the [Garmin website](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/compare.do?cID=143&compareProduct=87774&compareProduct=8701). The eTrex 30 supports GLONASS in addition to GPS, which (at least in theory) means more satellites and more accuracy.

Comment: great, thanks! Bad news for me, as I prefer the HCx's great display and usage... Also Tide tables and Garmin Custom Maps would be nice to have...

Comment: Lars, [here](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?cID=&pID=8701) and [here](http://www.garmin.cz/produkty/outdoor/mapove-gps/etrex-hcx-serie/etrex-legend-hcx.html) they write that HCx has a very sensitive chip, that works in forest, deep valleys and in cities (I was able to get my position in plane!), so this may more than outweight the eTrex 30 GLONASS. Where can one find information about sensitivity of eTrex 30's chip?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any information on the chip in the eTrex 30, but I wouldn't think that it's worse than the one in the previous model. There's a comparison accuracy of the eTrex 20 with some other Garmin models [here](http://gpstracklog.com/2011/10/garmin-etrex-30-review.html).